# How to Install edx in a sub-URI

Tags: python, django, edx

I've installed edx-platfrom on http://example.com/edx . How to resolve the problem with urls? I want to replace in url's / with /edx/.

Source code: https://github.com/edx/edx-platform

Comment: please provide more details on how you installed edx. Did you follow the instructions and used vagrant and vbox? Your acual url is not example.com, right? It is not clear to me if you want ddx folder out or in?

Comment: @ViniciusMiana can you please help me with an here?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21330920/feasibility-to-setup-an-open-source-platform-edx-http-en-wikipedia-org-wik