# feasibility to setup an Open Source Platform “edX” - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EdX

Tags: macos, openedx

I have just heard of this open source early in this morning, and hook into google for searching about this,but seems like google have limited options too.
I found this one https://github.com/edx/configuration/wiki/edX-Ubuntu-12.04-Installation ,but it is for ubuntu

I am using mac 10.8.3 ,my question is

1.is it possible to install it on my mac machine

2.Where can i find the downloads of this open source

3.Which is the best tutorial to install edX

With Regards

Answer (score 2):

1) Yes you can install the files on Mac, just that there isn't a guide in order to archive that. You can try to follow the Ubuntu guide posted and one by one check if the commands are compatible, or use a compatible command.

2) In order to get the files you need to use github so the link that you post is where the files are you can use a git clone in order to get the files on your mac.

3) The best tutorial is this one https://github.com/edx/configuration/wiki/edX-Ubuntu-12.04-64-bit-Installation. Remember that Ansible is in charge of the installation so we just need to run and wait

Hope that this helps